# SQL - Generate "missing rows" with a select

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question relates to SQL 2012 - 
Lets say I have 3 rows generated as follows:

```
Start Position = 10
End Position = 13
Value = 100

Start position = 14
End Position = 14
Value = 250

Start Position = 15
End Position = 25
Value = 300
```

on 3 rows .. 
Is there a way I can force SQL to write the output:

```
10 - 100
11 - 100
12 - 100
13 - 100
14 - 250
15 - 300
16 - 300
```

etc and so on and so forth

Been wracking the brains but cant  work out an easy way to do it

Thanks a lot

J

Comment: It's very easy to do that in code, say PHP, after retrieving this data. Doing it in SQL will probably involve some more wrangling.

Comment: One approach is to use a [numbers table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/), also known as a tally table.  These are incredibly handy for all sorts of things, including creating rows from values.

Comment: Frankly it is not clear to me.Can you show your input and desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a recursive CTE or a numbers table.  Assuming the gaps are no more than a few hundred or thousand:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master.spt_values
     )
select (t.startpos + n.n) as position, value
from t join
     n
     on t.startpos + n.n <= t.endpos;
```

Answer (score 0):

No database is complete without its table of numbers! Instructions on how to create one are all over the net, here is an example:

[Create a numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/)

I have a numbers table in my database, its called **t_numbers**, it has a single column "n" with a row for each number starting from 1. It goes up to 999,999 but it takes up very little space on disk. Once you have that, you can write something like this:

**set up a bit of data to use first**

```
    declare @Rows table
    (
        StartPos int,
        EndPos int,
        Value int
    )

    insert into @Rows values (10, 13, 100), (14, 14, 250), (15, 25, 300)
```

**If you want don't want gaps for nulls use an inner join**

```
    select n.n, Value
        from t_numbers n
            inner join @Rows r on n.n >= StartPos and n.n <= EndPos
```

**If you want the gaps then left join, but limit the return with a where clause**

```
    select n.n, Value
        from t_numbers n
            left join @Rows r on n.n >= StartPos and n.n <= EndPos
        where n <= (select MAX(EndPos) from @Rows)
```

Comment: Thankyou kind sir, really appreciated your feedback (y) top notch legend

Comment: Cheers! If you could mark as answer it would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou people! that did it

In the end I created a table of numbers (thankyou guys) 
+ said

CROSS JOIN MyNumbers

WHERE T.Real_Position between T.triangle_start_position and T.triangle_end_position

This gave me the exact resultset I was looking for